# How to memory allocate a pointer inside a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, allocation

I'm new in C programming (my main area is java) and in java there exists the ArrayList which I can make like

```
    ArrayList<Class> arraylist = new ArrayList<Class>();
```

where my class Class can have several items, such as int, or string.

In c, I found I cannot do that but need to do something like that, so I did this

```
    typedef struct vectorObject {
      int myInt;
      char *charPointer;
    } vectorObject;
```

I define a pointer of my structure like this:

```
    vectorObject *listVectorObject;
```

and using

```
    #define MAX_FILE_SIZE   50000
```

when I want to allocate the memory of that, I use this:

```
    int i;
    listVectorObject = malloc(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    if (listVectorObject == NULL ) {
         printf("Out of memory1\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_FILE_SIZE; i++) {
         listVectorObject[i].charPointer= malloc(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
         if (listVectorObject[i].charPointer == NULL ) {
              printf("Out of memory2\n");
              exit(1);
         }
    }
```

The problem is I always get a

```
    Out of Memory2
```

I already tried everything and I cannot find where my mistake is. Could you please help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: How much memory do you have in your machine? Is it 64-bit?

Comment: Are you sure you want `MAX_FILE_SIZE` iterations?

Comment: perhaps you have to cast `listVectorObject =(VectorObject *) malloc(MAX_FILE_SIZE);`  ?

Comment: Yeah, do you realize you're allocating approximately 2.5GB of memory here? `MAX_FILE_SIZE * MAX_FILE_SIZE = 2500000000`.

Comment: For starters, you aren't using `malloc` correctly.  Shouldn't it be `listVectorOject = malloc(MAX_FILE_SIZE * sizeof(VectorObject));`?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @unwind:  Sorry I fixed my comment. Old habits die hard I guess.

Comment: @aardvarkk this is the reason you're getting this error.  You're using too much memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want 50000 vectorObjects each with 50000 bytes char-buffer.

So look at this:

- first making a list of 1000 vectorObjects
- then for each of those allocating a memory chunk to the char-pointer

.

```
int i, howmany= 1000;
vectorObject *listVectorObject = malloc(sizeof(vectorObject)*howmany);  // list of 1000 vectorObjects
if (listVectorObject == NULL ) {
     printf("Out of memory1\n");
     exit(1);
}

// one file-size char-pointer for each vector object above
for (i = 0; i<howmany; i++) {
     listVectorObject[i].charPointer= malloc(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
     if (listVectorObject[i].charPointer == NULL ) {
          printf("Out of memory2\n");
          exit(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response! It was the memory! (I stupidly thought it would not affect it... changed it to a smaller number and it worked like a charm!)
Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad to hear.  Pls make sure to change the "sizeof(vectorObject)*howmany" in the first alloc also.

Comment: Already did it! Wow I love the speed of your responses! Thanks again and sorry to bother you with such a dumb question (In java is not necessary to do this so I was a little bit confused)

Comment: No worries, we already started there sometimes (and going fromm Java to C will be a path full of traps).